# MVC 5 - how can I send a SelectList from a controller to a dropdownlist and show the data text field with more than one property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm brand new to ASP MVC 5 so struggling with some concepts. What I'm trying to do is expand on what i'm seeing in the Html.DropDownList with more than just the one property. I have seen some other examples on stack overflow but what I'm doing is slightly different in how I'm sending the SelectList to the Razor cshtml page.

Code for Controller:

```
        public ActionResult Create(int? userID)
    {
        ViewBag.CourseID = new SelectList(db.Courses, "CourseID", "CourseName");

        var users = db.Users
        .Select(u => new
        {
           Text = u.FirstName + " " + u.Surname,
           Value = u.UserID
        }).ToList();

        if (userID == null)
        {
            ViewBag.UserIDList = new SelectList(users, "UserID", "FirstName", "Surname");
        }
        else
        {
            User linkedCourseUser = db.Users.Find(userID);
            ViewBag.UserIDList = new SelectList(users, "UserID", "FirstName", "Surname", linkedCourseUser.UserID);                
        }            
        return View();
    }
```

What I've tried on the view:

```
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserID, "UserID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">                                
            @Html.DropDownList("UserID", ViewBag.UserIDList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, null , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

So basically I'm trying to combine the First and Surname properties together before sending it to the Viewbag as some other people have suggested. The application will just error saying this:

```
DataBinding ... (error codes) does not contain a property with the name 'UserID'.
```

Any direction would be great!

Comment: Please format your code better so that it is more readable to other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it, like you know there are many different ways to kill a cat :)

I would modify the user class to look something like this. The name property will be a concatenation of first name and last name:

```
public class User
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     public string LastName { get; set; }

     public string Name
     {
          get
          {
               return FirstName + " " + LastName;
          }
     }
}
```

Create a view model that you will send to the view. You will need to add your validation code here:

```
public class CreateViewModel
{
     public int UserId { get; set; }

     public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Prepare your view model that will be sent to the view in the controller. Create a user repository that will handle your data retrieval:

```
public ActionResult Create(int? userID)
{
     CreateViewModel model = new CreateViewModel();

     if (userID == null)
     {
          model.Users = userRepository.GetAll();
     }
     else
     {
          model.Users = userRepository.GetByUserID(userID);
     }

     return View(model);
}
```

Create your view to accept the above created view model:

```
@model MyProject.DomainModel.ViewModels.CreateViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(
     m => m.UserId,
     new SelectList(Model.Users, "Id", "Name", Model.UserId),
     "-- Select --"
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserId)
```

This is a very watered down version, but it will put you on the right path forward. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Brendon - being new to this I didnt consider adding an extra property to do that. A handy technique.

Comment: Thanks.. and sorry it took so long for someone to 1 up a very well put together answer.